# Does mongodb use index search in lookup stage?

Tags: mongodb

I'm querying a collection with aggregate function in MongoDB and I have to look up some other collections in its aggregation. But I have a question about it:
Does MongoDB use indexes for foreignField? I wasn't able to figure this out and I searched
everywhere for this but I didn't get my answer. It must certainly use indexes for it but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to determine how the database is executing a query is to generate and examine the `explain` output for the operation. With aggregations that include the `$lookup` stage specifically you will want to use the more verbose `.explain("executionStats")` mode. You may also utilize [the `$indexStats` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/) to confirm that the usage count of the intended index is increasing.

The best answer we can give based on the limited information in the question is: MongoDB will probably use the index. Query execution behavior, including index usage, depends on the situation and the version. If you provide more information in your question, then we can provide more specific information. There is also some details about index usage on [the `$lookup` documentation page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).